# Incorrect Datetime Value : '2014-10-19 00:00:00' for column time at row 2300

Tags: mysql, datetime

> Incorrect Datetime Value : '2014-10-19 00:00:00' for column time at
>   row 2300

How can I fix SQL Replace query to avoid incorrect Datetime Value : '2014-10-19 00:00:00' for column time at row 2300.

In Brazil, DST occurs on Sunday, October 19, 2014, 12:00:00 Midnight clocks were turned forward 1 hour to Sunday, October 19, 2014, 1:00:00 AM local daylight time instead and MYSQL server just does not like 2014-10-19 00:00:00 as its not really valid time , it should be 2014-10-19 01:00:00

Mysql server installed on OS having Timezone (UTC-03:00)Barasilia

```
CREATE TABLE `Table1` (
  `Group` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `Type` enum('Electric_Energy','Electric_Apparent','Gas_Volume','Gas_Energy','Water_Volume','Water_Energy','Thermal_Energy','Steam_Weight','Temperature','Carbon_Emission','Fuel_Volume') COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `Aggregation` enum('Sum','Avg','Max','Min') COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `Period` char(1) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `Timestamp` timestamp NOT NULL,
  `Value` decimal(38,10) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Group`,`Timestamp`,`Type`,`Aggregation`,`Period`),
  KEY `IDX_Table1_group_period_timestamp` (`Group`,`Period`,`Timestamp`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_Table1_Group` FOREIGN KEY (`Group`) REFERENCES `group1` (`ID`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin ROW_FORMAT=COMPRESSED;




CREATE TABLE `Table2` (
  `ID` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `Value` decimal(38,10) NOT NULL,
  `Timestamp` timestamp NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`,`Timestamp`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_Table2_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`ID`) REFERENCES `Table3` (`ID`) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin;







REPLACE INTO `Table1` SELECT 898 `Group`, "Water_Volume" `Type`, "Sum" `Aggregation`, "D" `Period`, CONCAT(DATE_FORMAT(`t1`.`Timestamp`, "%Y-%m-%d"), " 00:00:00") `Timestamp`,Sum(`t1`.`Value`) `Value` FROM (SELECT SUM(`Value`) `Value`, `Timestamp` FROM `Table2` WHERE `ID` IN (1438, 1439) AND `Timestamp` BETWEEN "2014-10-12 00:00:00" AND "2014-10-19 23:59:59" GROUP BY `Timestamp`) `t1` GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(`t1`.`Timestamp`, "%Y-%m-%d");
```

Comment: It doesn't address your actual question, but I'd suggest that unless you are sure your list of selections are not going to change, or are prepared for when they do, I would avoid enum fields; you are almost always better off with references to lookup tables. When you add a new value to an enum list, MySQL has to recreate the entire table; also, they tend to have weird behavior in some situations and their support through various APIs can be spotty.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply . I am asking here about how to fix SQL Replace query to avoid incorrect Datetime Value : '2014-10-19 00:00:00' for column time at row 2300

Comment: Yeah, I am not sure how MySQL can consider that an invalid value...or are you saying that is not the value you are expecting?  Maybe the CONCAT needs wrapped in a CAST? or is it possible that both table2 records have the same value for the `Timestamp` field, causing replace into to attempt to update the same row twice?

Comment: I tend to stay away from REPLACE INTO as a general rule as it has too many potentials for weirdness; like the potential to remove multiple rows and replace them with a single new one (when different unique keys are matched on different rows).

Comment: In Brazil, DST occurs on Sunday, October 19, 2014, 12:00:00 Midnight clocks were turned forward 1 hour to 
Sunday, October 19, 2014, 1:00:00 AM local daylight time instead and MYSQL server just does not like 2014-10-19 00:00:00 as its not really valid time , it should be 2014-10-19 01:00:00

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of an official way to compensate for daylight savings time holes, but something like this should be simple, one time use, way to handle it.

```
CONCAT(DATE_FORMAT(`t1`.`Timestamp`, "%Y-%m-%d")
         , IF(DATE_FORMAT(`t1`.`Timestamp`, "%Y-%m-%d")="2014-10-19", " 01:00:00",  " 00:00:00")
      )
```

If it does not jump around from year to year like it feels like it does in the US, you could probably come up with a more permanent test like

```
MONTH(`t1`.`Timestamp`) = 10 AND DAYOFMONTH(`t1`.`Timestamp`) = 19
```

...or just use 01:00:00 uniformly since you'll need to account/adjust for it on those dates anyway.